# Calculating Probability avoiding painful Iteration

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random, stochastic-integrals

A person walks 2 meters to the left or 1 meter to the right with 50:50 chance.

Point A is 3 meters to the left and Point B is 3 meters to the Right

What is the probability of reaching poing A first?

For example, with just two consecutive moves to the left, the person can walk 4 meters reaching the 3 meter goal. Unfortunately when i try to solve this by iteration, i quickly realize there are infinite scenarios.

Imagine -1 -1 +2 -1 -1 +2 -1 -1 +2 -1 -1 +2 ... as you can see...you can keep going staying close to 0, without reaching 3 or -3 (Left or Right) This makes me believe there needs to be some infinite sum or integral to solve for this cases with smaller and smaller probability.

By using a computer program i found out that, if you raise the distance of point A and B from 3 to 10 or 100 or 1000... the probability of reaching point A first starts to go to 100%, despite the distance from the center of A and B staying equal. I imagine some log function or root function hidden in there.

Comment: Sounds like a [random walk.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)

Comment: Got something from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the solution is to consider, for every $-3\leqslant k\leqslant3$, the probability $p_k$ to hit A first starting from $k$. Then $p_{-3}=0$, $p_3=p_4=1$ and the Markov property after one step yields $$p_2=\tfrac12(1+p_1)\quad p_1=\tfrac12(1+p_0)\quad p_0=\tfrac12(p_2+p_{-1})\quad p_{-1}=\tfrac12(p_{-2}+p_1)\quad p_{-2}=\tfrac12(0+p_0)$$ Solving this $5\times5$ affine system yields the desired probability $p_0$.

...That is, unless I am mistaken, $$p_0=\tfrac45$$

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your solution, but i'm not that smart to generalize this. Lets say... Point A is 100 meters to the left and point B is 100 meters to the right. The possible moves now are 11m to the left or 10m to the right. Does the complexity increase? Is there any pattern that connects the different inputs?

Comment: That the probability to exit $(-n,n)$ by its right end goes to $1$ when $n\to\infty$ is easy but to get an exact expression of this probability for every $n$ might not be very direct. Which one is your question?